# For your application it's better to have your own online database or to use some online database service?

Tags: database, app

I would like to create an application that will interacts with an online database and i want to host my own online database on an old computer, but i think that in this case i should handle the security and other thing by myself. The problem is that i don't know if this i'm able to handle this stuff. So it's something difficult to do alone? What other options would you suggest?

Comment: *i don't know if this i'm able to handle this stuff* - and you think strangers from the internet, who don't know you, will know better if you will be able "to handle this stuff"? Seriously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of very different skills and needs at stake here:

- on one side creating an app: that’s the cool part of the story. You decide when you work on your app.
- on another side, operating a service: that’s the hard part of the story: your service needs to be available 24/24 and 7/7, your old computer might have to absorb peek in demands where one computer is no longer enough, you’ll have to ensure a periodic backup (the question is never IF a hard disk will fail but WHEN), not to speak of the security concerns, the application of patches and a lot of other topics.

So, unless you are a company with a temp of experts in all those domains, you should really think of taking care of what you can deliver for sure, and subcontracting the remainder, either to a traditional hosting company or in the cloud.